# Locale Support for antd Form requiredMark

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

In antd Form tag, "requiredMark" api supports two values. Boolean (true|false) and string "optional". This optional mark is showing the text "(optional)" in every optional fields. But my case is when i change the locale from en_GB to some other like ta_IN, the "(optional)" text should also change as per the locale.

Is there any solution for this? Like i can give my own text for representing optional field mark?

`<Form form={form} name="regContactDetails" requiredMark="optional" layout="vertical">...</Form>`

[Form Item requiredMark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Ecs.png)

Answer (score 0):

here a trick for "dynamic state", create a `optional` as get prop

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    get option(){ return  t('optional')},
});

<Form form={form} name="regContactDetails" requiredMark={state.optional} layout="vertical">...</Form>
```